# Initialize a Child Class from an instance of Parent class Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I am kind of new to OOP (I think I understand the basics now), so I'm struggling with something:
I am currently making a personal iOS app that involves using events from the iPhone Calendar. I wanted to add properties to the built in `EKEvent` class but I read that's not possible with extensions.
So I decided to make my own Class, called `Event`, that will inherit from `EKEvent` and add the properties I want.

But I'm struggling with the initialization for this class: I would like to initialize `Event` from an instance of `EKEvent` since I'm getting EKEvents when I fetch the events of my Calendar, but I can't find a way to do it. I looked but didn't find a similar questions for Swift, they are using super.init() which is not what I want to do.

Here's my class, I found a workaround as you can see but I'd like to understand how to do it with inheritance if it's possible ^^

```swift
class Event {    // Deleted the : EKEvent here to test my workaround
    public var matiere: String = ""
    public var matiereId: String = ""
    public var prof: String = ""
    public var salle: String = ""
    public var type: String = ""
    
    public var ekEvent: EKEvent
    public var duration: DateInterval
    public var hoursDuration: Int
    public var minutesDuration: Int
    
    init(ekEvent: EKEvent) {
        /* Here is my workaround, if I need to access properties from EKEvent I'll use
        self.ekEvent.startDate (for example) */
        self.ekEvent = ekEvent

        self.duration = DateInterval(start: ekEvent.startDate, end: ekEvent.endDate)
        
        self.hoursDuration = Int(duration.duration) / 3600
        self.minutesDuration = (Int(self.duration.duration) - (3600 * self.hoursDuration)) / 60
    }
    
}
```

Thanks in advance and excuse my English I'm French =D

Comment: You're storing the `EKEvent` into `self.ekEvent`, and you can access `startDate` on that. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Yes it's working but I wanted to know if there was a "cleaner" solution with inheritance but it seems like there isn't, thanks for your answer =D

Comment: Which part are you trying to make cleaner? I can't even figure out which part of this you're trying to improve

Comment: Instead of using Event.ekEvent.startDate I wanted to make Event inherit from EKEvent and then initialize Event from an instance of EKEvent, to then only have to use Event.startDate (or whatever EKEvent property I might need later)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but I guess what confused me was "Deleted the : EKEvent here to test my workaround" So you've already tried inheritance, but switched away from it to test your "workaround". Workaround for what? _What was the issue?_

Comment: My problem was to know if it was possible to initialize a child class from an instance of its parent Class. When I tried inheritance, my app didn't build or crashed because I couldn't find a way to do this.
I searched here and the only things I found involved super.init() (which is not what I wanted to do since my goal is to use an already initialized Parent Class to initialize my Child Class), that's when I switched to this workaround.
Sorry if I'm unclear I'm still learning OOP + English is not my native language ^^

Comment: Ah okay, I think I understand. First off, when you have an existing `EKEvent` object, the process of transforming it into your `Event` class (if one existed), would involve expanding the object's memory layout to accommodate the stored properties required by `Event`. There isn't a (non-hacky) way to do that in-place. So in any case, you'll need to allocate a new object for the job. From there, you have two options: inherit `EKEvent`, or wrap it. Wrapping is what you showed here, and it works pretty well. With inheritance, your initializer will always need to call the super implementation to...

Comment: ... give the superclass' initializer a chance to do its work. Broadly speaking, there's two ways that could work. Either the superclass can have a "copy constructor" (an initializer that takes `EKEvent` as a parameter and initializes itself by copying from it), or a memberwise initializer that takes all the stored properties as parameters (this is fragile however, because adding new stored properties needs a breaking change to this initializer's API). Neither of these initializers exist on EKEvent, so indeed, you'll need to go the wrapping route.

Comment: Oook thanks a lot for your explanations, it makes it more clear to me, so I'll continue with wrapping then (and might go and look into it =D)
Thanks again ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glad to hear you're getting into OOP!

So the way you've seen people doing this `using super.init()` is the most common and accepted way to achieve what you want, but in this case, the init function that you would want to override hasn't been marked as `open`.

This essentially means you can't override it and init your own variables, then call super.init. So your approach is completely fair in this case.

#### Streamline the process

so, as an idea, if you're aiming to try and make this a little more streamline, you could do something like this:

```swift
extension EKEvent {
    
    func createEvent() -> Event {
        .init(ekEvent: self)
    }
    
}
```

This will allow you to now do this: `ekEvent.createEvent()` and then this will return an event object which you can use.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I'll stick to this then if I can't initialize from an EKEvent instance =D 
(Thanks for the suggestion I wasn't doing it like this ^^)